# How do I control my second Android tablet mouse?

Tags: remote-access

I have two Android tablet devices, and I want to use the first device to control the second device. The first device should act just like a keyboard and mouse. But I can't find the solution to do this. I am using Android 2.2, and the Android OS have the mouse cursor.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to implement this in a program (since this originated on SO) or are you looking for an already existing method for doing this? Your question is somewhat vague, so perhaps you can clarify a bit.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this work, and I find some point about that I must to Root the android so that can control the mouse and keyboard.

But I just know that. Maybe someone can give me some suggestion. 

Thanks~

I'm sorry. My English is a little weak. ><"

Comment: You can control the keyboard without being root with [Tablet Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tournesol.tabletremote&hl=es). But I didn't find an app to control the mouse without being root :/

Comment: And I found this [Google Application for Android TV Box](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tv.remote&hl=es), but I need it for the normal Android :(

Answer (score 3):

Install [DroidMote Server](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.videomap.droidmoteserver) on the one you want to be controlled and [DroidMote Client](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.videomap.droidmoteclient) on the one with which you want to do the controlling.